# Unable to select combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, module

I have a combo box named "Facility" that has been added as a form control to an Excel 2010 worksheet. I also have a module titled "AdjustmentsAmount" that is running the below method on a form button click. I've tried several methods of accessing the form control, and none work, also listed below. Can anyone shed light on this subject please?

Code

```
'Clears all run specifications
Sub clearRunSpecs_click()
    Dim resp As String
    resp = MsgBox("This will clear all run specifications. Are you sure you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
    If (resp = vbYes) Then
        Worksheets("AdjustmentsAmount").Unprotect "pass"
        Range("D3").Clear
        Range("D3").Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
        Range("D3").BorderAround LineStyle:=XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic, Color:=RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Range("D3").Locked = False
        Range("D4").Clear
        Range("D4").Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
        Range("D4").BorderAround LineStyle:=XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic, Color:=RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Range("D4").Locked = False
        Range("B4").Clear
        Range("B4").Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
        Range("B4").BorderAround LineStyle:=XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic, Color:=RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Range("B4").Locked = False
        Range("A17:D22").Clear
        Range("A17:D22").Merge
        Range("A17:D22").Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
        Range("A17:D22").BorderAround LineStyle:=XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium, ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic, Color:=RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Range("A17:D22").VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("A17:D22").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Facility").ListIndex = -1
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("ZeroBalance").Value = xlOff
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Balance<Adj").Value = xlOff
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Balance=Adj").Value = xlOff
        Worksheets("AdjustmentsAmount").Protect "pass"
    End If
End Sub
```

Methods tried

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Facility")
ActiveSheet.Facility
ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("Facility")
Application.Facility
```

I have accessed checkboxes in the same method using `ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("NAME")` and that worked fine. However, I can't seem to get ahold of the combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set a blank line to be ListIndex1 and used:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Facility").ControlFormat.ListIndex = 1
```

to access it. I am presuming that's what you need?

Comment: I would like the box to reset to a null state. I assumed this was listindex = -1 (as I have seen on a site prior. I can't recall which now), but that is not allowed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hidden - you can access the listbox or combobox like this:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes("Facility").OLEFormat.Object.Value
```